# Determine the domain of convergence of series $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{2n+1}{(n+1)^5}(x+2)^{1-2n}$.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Good day!! I have some problems with those exercises

Determine the domain of convergence of series $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{2n+1}{(n+1)^5}(x+2)^{1-2n}$

I think about Abel and Dirichlet theorem but seem that it doesn't help. Can you guys help me or give me some hints ? Thank you so much for helping

Comment: What happens around $x=-2$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $x\ne-2$, you have\begin{align}\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\left|\frac{2(n+1)+1}{((n+1)+1)^5}(x+2)^{1-2(n+1)}\right|}{\left|\frac{2n+1}{(n+1)^5}(x+2)^{1-2n}\right|}&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2n+3}{2n+1}\frac{(n+1)^5}{(n+2)^5}|x+2|^{-2}\\&=|x+2|^{-2}\end{align}Therefore, your series converges absolutely if $|x+2|>1$ and diverges if $|x+2|<1$. The remaining cases are $x=-1$ and $x=-3$. In both cases, the series converges, since$$\left|\frac{2n+1}{(n+1)^5}(x+2)^{1-2n}\right|=\frac{2n+1}{(n+1)^5}$$and the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2n+1}{(n+1)^5}$ converges, by the comparison test, since$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{2n+1}{(n+1)^5}}{\frac1{n^4}}=2$$and the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^4}$ converges.